# How are filenames stored when they're passed as command line arguments in C?

Tags: c

For my C project, I had to check the format of 2 files and had to pass them as cmd line args. Depending on which files were passed, different functions were supposed to be invoked for which I had to compare something like this :

```
if(argv[1] == "file.txt") {
    func1();
}else{
    func2();
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: That’s not how you compare strings. See [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: The file names that you pass stored exactly how you write them in the command line arguments. Try : if (strcmp(argv[1], "file.txt") == 0), and dont forget include <string.h>.

Comment: `argv[1] == "file.txt"` is comparing if `argv[1]` and `"file.txt"` are in the same spot in memory - which is unlikely ever to occur, not whether the content are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to compare 2 strings but you are comparing char * instead. Use strcmp instead of == operator.